# Get closest input in a for loop if button click with same classes(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to get the value of the closest input field (subjectId), which contanis the id, in other input. But it always takes the last subjectId.

The HTML-Code:

```
@foreach($grades As $grade)
<tr class="subjectGrades">
    <td class="min-td-size">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left min-margin-right" class="overviewShowSubjectGrades" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShowGrades">Show Grades</button>                              
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" class="overviewAddGrade" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddGrade">+</button>
    <input type="hidden" class="subjectId" value="{!! $grade->subjectId !!}">
    </td>                        
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The JQuery-Code:

```
$('.overviewAddGrade').click(function () {
        var subjectId = $(this).closest('.subjectId').val();    
        $('#modalSubjectId').val() = subjectId;    
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a `.` in your class selector for `subjectId`, but the problem is `closest` searches up the DOM tree - while your element is a sibling. You can use `closest` to get the parent, then `find` to get the target elem:

```
var subjectId = $(this).closest("td").find('.subjectId').val();
```

Comment: Thanks omg there are a lot of fails, two class-tags in button and others but now it works.